# Cron task executes every hour instead of every 3 hours

Tags: ubuntu, cron, scheduling

I have a cron task:

```
$ crontab -l
*/180 * * * * /my_script.py
```

For some reason, as I can see from /var/log/syslog, it executes every hour instead of every 3 hours. Why is that?

Comment: Because your * for hours is telling crond to execute the task every hour.

Answer (score 5):

I guess it will trigger whenever the current minute is a multiple of 180, i.e. on the hour (0 minutes). I'd try

```
0 */3 * * * * my_script.py
```

instead. (Interestingly, `man 5 crontab` is a bit silent on what happens when you specify a step that does not divide the number of hours/minutes/days, but I guess `*/17` would be the same as `0,17,34,51`.)

Comment: Indeed.  the `/n` notation doesn't fire every time that time unit is divisible by the specified number, but rather every `n` intervals.

Comment: how about every hour then?

Comment: @Kurama: That would just be `0 * …`, or `0 0-23 ...`, "on 0 minute of hours 0-23".

Comment: I'd like to also point out that cron runs in localtime, so "every 3 hours" will break twice a year if you're in a locale infected by daylight saving time.

Comment: Not if you make sure the start and end of the cron period completely bracket the skipped/repeated time period.  So, 0 0/3 * * * will fire at 00:00, 03:00, 06:00, etc.  It is the time period from 1-3 on Sunday that is susceptible to DST.  Once per year, it repeats 1 am to 2 am. Once per year 2 am jumps straight to 3 am.

Comment: @RickRyker ...and so it won't run every three hours on those occasions, like derobert said.

Comment: Well, if you want it to run a process strictly on a 3 hour schedule, then use a cron task that repeats every hour and load/read/save a variable from a file that counts 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ad infinitum, and only run when it is 0. Just be aware that this will drift forward and backward an hour when DST starts and finishes.